# python xlxml xpath expression to match substring in attribute

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Let's say I have the below XML

```
<root>
   <element class="Page" style="background: url(/images/RlEguQY3_ghsdr.png?1324483033) repeat left top;" />
   <element class="User" />
   <element class="Image" src="/images/bg.png" />
</root>
```

I am looking for a xpath expression which
 1) matches all elements that have **/images** in the **style** attribute
and
2) matches all Image elements that have **/images** in the **src** attribute

Any help greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What does the XPath expression you are already using look like?  What unexpected results are you seeing when you try to use the XPath expression you have devised yourself?

Comment: The truth is, that I have not anything

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 //element[contains(@style, '/images') or (@class='Image' and contains(@src, '/images'))]
```

(or something similar) should do it.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a xpath expression which 1) matches all elements that
>   have `/images` in the `style` attribute

**Directly translated to XPath**:

```
/*/element[contains(@style, '/images')]
```

. . .

> ...
>
> and 2) matches all `Image` elements that have `/images` in the `src`
>   attribute

**There are no `Image` elements in the provided XML document**. Probably you meant: `element` elements with `class` attribute with value `"Image"`:

```
/*/element[@class='Image'][contains(@src, '/images')]
```

**Combined together, the two XPath expressions above give this**:

```
/*/element
    [contains(@style, '/images')
   or
    @class='Image' and contains(@src, '/images')
    ]
```

It seems to me that most probable for the second requirement above you actually want the value of the `src` attribute to actually ***start with*** `"/images"`. If so, the more precise XPath expression is:

```
/*/element
    [contains(@style, '/images')
   or
    @class='Image' and starts-with(@src, '/images')
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre. Very nice description

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [predicates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates), your predicate expressions will use the [contains](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) function.  The [union operator](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-sets) might also come in handy.